# Is jenkins build description an environment variable?

Tags: jenkins

Is the jenkins build description an environment variable?

I have a job that sets a build description and I want to pass that value as a "predefined parameter" to the "Trigger parameterized build on other project". Is there something like a ${BUILD_DESCRIPTION} variable that I can use?

Comment: I am aware of the available list of Jenkins environment variables, but I was wondering if the build description can be accessed in some way as a environment variable to be passed to downstream projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could kludge this by writing the build description to a properties file somewhere under your upstream job's workspace, in the format

```
builddesc=My Build Description
```

Then you can use the "Parameters from properties file" option in the "Trigger parameterized build on other project" post build step, and the build description will be available as an environment variable (with the same name you gave it in the properties file) in your downstream build.

Comment: Thank you very much Gareth.. that was exactly what I needed. Worked perfectly! I've been able to pass values to my downstream jobs.

Answer (score 5):

No. You can find a list of all environment variables at `http://<yourjenkins>/env-vars.html/`.

Comment: Remove the slash at the end of the url to access the list (with the slash, google-chrome download the file rather than displaying it)